# Need to use extra option while compiling c code which includes <math.h>

Tags: c, compiler-errors, math.h, math.sqrt

Whenever I include math.h to my c code I can't compile without the -lm option. I get this error message:

```
d.o: In function `refresh_position':
d.c:(.text+0x4df): undefined reference to `sqrt'
d.c:(.text+0x524): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can compile it with just typing -lm but my teacher says that if code doesn't work i will get 0 point from that homework. I want to know is this error occurs because of my code or because of my computer or c library. I have to be sure about it will run without any error on my teachers computer.

Comment: If your teacher uses an implementation with the math library separate from the rest of the standard library, she should know how to link it all together when needed. I think it's an error to give 0 points for homework that requires `pow()` or `sin()` if the teacher does not know how to use her tools (unless, of course, it's assumed to be programming for free-standing environments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some implementations such as gcc do not link the math library (called `libm.a` on most *nix implementations) by default, which is why you need to include the `-lm` when building the code.

Your teacher *should* be aware of issues like this, and as long as your code is using `sqrt` and other math routines *correctly* (using the right type for the inputs and output), he or she should be able to build your code such that it will run.